# Antiderivatives and definite integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Compute the following integral:
$$
I=\int_{0}^{1}\bigg(\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt\bigg)dx
$$
**Motivation:** From time to time, i intend to post here challenging questions  -together with proposed answers/solutions- which i frequently give for practise to some of my students (in an introductory calculus course).
I am doing this with the understanding that this is not only accepted but furthermore encouraged by the community. The benefits can be twofold: on the one hand this contributes to building a library with well-posed questions and reliable answers (to be used in-class or online) and on the other hand i always hope that this may result in improving (or sometimes correcting) the proposed questions/answers and discovering new approaches/solutions from other users as well.

Comment: One approach is to change the order of integration,                                                   $$
I=\int_{0}^{1}\bigg(\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt\bigg)dx=\int_{0}^{1}\bigg(\int_{t}^{0}\frac{1}{1+t^2}dx\bigg)dt=-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t}{1+t^2}dt
$$

Comment: @clark: I am not sure i understand how you are changing the order of integration. Maybe it would be interesting to add some more details and then post as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(t)=\frac{1}{1+t^2}$, $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $F(x)=\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt=\int_{1}^{x}f(t)dt$, $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Consequently, $F'(x)=f(x)$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and:
$$
I=\int_{0}^{1}\bigg(\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt\bigg)dx=\int_{0}^{1}F(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1}(x)'F(x)dx=
$$
$$
=[xF(x)]_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}xF'(x)dx=F(1)-\int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx=0-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{1+x^2}dx=
$$
$$
=-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1+x^2)'}{1+x^2}dx=-\frac{1}{2}[\ln(1+x^2)]_{0}^{1}=-\frac{\ln 2}{2}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{align}\displaystyle \int_0^1\int_1^x\frac{dt}{1+t^2}\cdot dx&=\int_0^1\left(\arctan(x)-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)dx\\&=\bigg[x\arctan(x)-\frac 12\ln(1+x^2)-\frac{\pi}4x\bigg]_0^1=-\frac12\ln(2)\end{align}$

Comment: Nice! You are using here two formulae: $$\int\frac{1}{\alpha^2+x^2}dx=\frac{1}{\alpha}\arctan\frac{x}{\alpha}+c$$ (for $\alpha=1$) and $$\int\arctan xdx=x\arctan x-\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+x^2)$$ as well.

Comment: In fact this is exactly as yours with expliciting $F$, because finding the anti-derivative of $\arctan$ uses integration by parts, and $F(1)=0$ is $1\arctan(1)-\frac{\pi}4.1=0$.