# Antiderivatives and definite integrals - 2

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Prove that the function
$$
f(x)=x^2\int_{0}^{1}t\sin^2(tx)dt
$$
is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$ and determine the formula $f'(x)$ of its derivative.

**Motivation:** Exactly as in: [Antiderivatives and definite integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3348659/195021)

Answer (score 1):

For all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
f(x)=x^2\int_{0}^{1}t\sin^2(tx)dt=\int_{0}^{1}x^2t\sin^2(tx)dt=\int_{0}^{1}(xt)\sin^2(tx)xdt
$$
Now, let $u=xt$ thus $du=xdt$ ($x$ is considered to be a constant when integrating with respect to $t$). For $t=0,1$, we get $u=0,x$, respectively. Hence
$$
f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}u\sin^2 udu, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x\in\mathbb{R}
$$
Consequently, $f$ is a differentiable function in $\mathbb{R}$ and its derivative is given by
$$
f'(x)=x\sin^2x
$$

Comment: The last line follows from part 1 of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: @Axion004: yes, you are right.